# Colocar una fecha determinada en un input type ="date"

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente input

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="input-hasta"   > A Fecha  :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
   <div class="input-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="input-hasta" name="hasta" tabindex="2"  
         maxlength="10" size="20">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quiero que al cargar la página contenga 31/12/2020 o el año que sea en vez de dd/mm/aaaa
He probado lo siguiente:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var n =  new Date();
   var y = n.getFullYear();
   var m = 12;
   var d = 31;
   var newfecha =d+"/"+m+"/"+y;

   
   $("#input-hasta").val(newfecha);
});
```

Sin resultado ; ¿Dónde me equivoco?
Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: El formato que pasas para establecer el valor de fecha es incorrecto, debe ser: `"yyyy-mm-dd"`. Por ejemplo: `let newfecha = \`${y}-${m}-${d}\`;`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras .en el recuadro de input aparece dd/mm/aaa,  parece lógico pensar que espera ese formato  ,  he cambiado el formado a: var newfecha =y+"/"+m+"/"+d; y con comillas  sin resultado alguno ;  let newfecha = `${y}-${m}-${d}`;no se que es de todas formas tampoco funciona

Comment: Puede parecer *lógico*, pero te muestra ese formato debido a la configuración local del cliente. Por otro lado, el estándar es una cadena con la forma `yyyy-mm-dd` (no se usa `"/"` como separador). En cuanto a esto: `let newfecha = \`${y}-${m}-${d}\`;` es un [*literal template*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings). Debes escribirlo con los `back ticks` que se muestran en mi comentario. Saludos

Comment: @EDiaz, una cosa es cómo se muestra el valor a introducir, el navegador lo adapta de acuerdo a idioma y preferencias de usuario; otra cosa es el valor que se debe asignar en la etiqueta, revisa la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date)

Comment: @EDiaz dehecho lo que dice Mauricio Contreras es correcto, lo pongo como respuesta

Comment: @Mauricio0 Contreras Funcionó ,he de reconocer que el siguiente código  let newfecha = `${y}-${m}-${d}`; es la primera vez que lo veo ,he marcado tu respuesta como positiva,gracias

Comment: @triby ,tienes toda la razón ,he marcado tu respuesta como positiva ,gracias

Answer (score 1):

Como comento @Mauricio Contreras la respuesta es esa y aca esta la implementacion

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var n = new Date();
  var y = n.getFullYear();
  var m = 12;
  var d = 31;
  var newfecha = `${y}-${m}-${d}`;
  $("#input-hasta").val(newfecha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" class="form-control" id="input-hasta" name="hasta" tabindex="2" maxlength="10" size="20">
```

Cabe resaltar que esta parte `${y}-${m}-${d}` es lo mismo que `y+"-"+m+"-"+d`